# Rake Task using Whenever Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to send emails daily weekly and monthly accordingly what user has selected. How can I do it using whenever gem.

Below is my rake file:

```
namespace :send_trending_deals do
  desc "TODO"
  task email_trending_deals: :environment do
    @app_users = AppUser.joins(:notification).where("recieve_trending_deals = ?", true).to_a
    @app_users.each do |app_user|
      DealNotifier.send_trending_deal(app_user).deliver_now
      puts "#{app_user.id} Email sent successfully"
    end
  end
end
```

Schedule.rb:

```
every 4.hours do
    rake "send_trending_deals:email_trending_deals"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Daily

```
every :day, at: '10:00' do
   #run task
end
```

Weekly

```
every :sunday, at: '13:00' do
   #run task
end
```

Monthly

```
every :month, at: '12:00' do
   #run task
end
```

Comment: and for bi-weekly.

Comment: 'every : sunday' is weekly, you can pick any day of the week

Comment: I want to send twice in a week.

Comment: `every [:sunday, :monday], at: '12:00' `